# Number of views inside the Site Usage's "Popular content in the last 7 days", does it show the number in the last 7 days ONLY

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-usage

When I access the Site Setting >> Site Usage page, i got these results inside the "Popular content in the last 7 days":-

[image]

my question is if the number of unique users the report is showing is for the last 7 days only or for all the days since the page/document was created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be for the last 7 days only. You could refer to this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-usage-data-for-your-sharepoint-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e

> Popular content
>
> Shows the most popular content on the site sorted by site pages, news
> posts, and documents. Popular content can be sorted by unique viewers,
> total views, or time spent for site pages and news posts. This report
> is available for the last 7 days.

Comment: thanks a lot for the valuable reply